# Delphi XE5 and FormatSettings

Tags: delphi

I am changing FormatSettings inside my application. Let's say computer's local currency is set to $ and I would like to use € in my app. I can change it using the following code.

```
FormatSettings.CurrencyString := '€';
```

However, if i go to regional settings and change it there, my FormatSettings revert back. I believe there should be a way to keep it safe. Do you know any solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

You can deal with this by avoiding the global shared format settings variable, `FormatSettings`, that has been deprecated for years now.

Instead create and populate a local variable of type `TFormatSettings`. Pass that to all functions that rely on format settings. It's only the global format settings variable that is updated when the user makes changes.

```
var
  fs: TFormatSettings;
....
fs := TFormatSettings.Create;
fs.CurrencyString := '€';
```

You might prefer to make this a global variable which you set up at startup and then never modify, if it really never should change.

Comment: I only need to keep CurrencyString and CurrencyFormat settings safe. The rest should change. That's why i can not get sure. I can even wait for WM_WININICHANGE but what if i need to change decimalformat?

Comment: You just need to do what I said in the answer

Comment: When i create fs, it doesn't change the CurrencyString in my app

Comment: No. You have do what I said. *Pass that to all functions that rely on format settings.* Whenever you convert, pass your settings.

Comment: David what i need to do is to change FormatSettings. I am using FormatSettings in hundereds of places as well as 3rd party components.

Comment: I mean even in a component like CurrencyEdit. It uses FormatSettings. so i need to change application wide format settings. Accept all other changes except CurrencyString and CurrencyFormat

Comment: No. That's not what you need.

Comment: But that's what i want :) What do you mean? Are you asking me to change everything i refer to FormatSettings?

Comment: Yes. That's what you should do. Properly encapsulated though.

Comment: I did what you said in your anser and my edits still show $ instead of €. I am using TCurrencyEdit and i believe it use FormatSettings...

Comment: I can only guess at what your edit control is. Don't expect to fix this in 5 minutes.

Comment: @blacksun If it is the `TCurrencyEdit` from RxLib then look at http://sourceforge.net/p/rxlib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Units/rxCurrEdit.pas line 892ff

Comment: @black - Report a bug for the Rx control's successor TJvValidateEdit that it use the Format override that doesn't take a TFormatSettings. The jvcl control should use the other overload and pass JclSysUtils.JclFormatSettings instead. I don't have the latest jvcl though, you may want to check first. Then use that control if it solves your problem. Or modify Rx source.

Comment: Actually i can not risk it. I prefer to change FormatSettings and keep it safe. I have answered my own solution here

Comment: @black - Looking at the source SirRufo linked, you should be able to enter whatever you wan to the DisplayFormat property. Did you check it?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes i did but fixing 3rd party component was not what i was looking for. Did you read my answer?

Comment: @black - I'm not suggesting modifying source code. The control has a 'DisplayFormat' property that you should be able to modify in OI or at run-time.

Comment: Configure this control using the `DisplayFormat` property. It makes sense to work with the system rather than fighting it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is what i did to solve my own problem. What i wanted to do is simply to change `FormatSettings.CurrencyString` and `FormatSettings.CurrencyFormat` application wide and save them safe. I can do this easily but when i go to Regional settings and edit Currency, my app reverts it back. I have found 2 solutions:

1.Set `Application.UpdateFormatSettings := False;` However, you won't get any other changes either. I mean nothing will be updated.

2.This one solved my problem. Just listen `WM_WININICHANGE` and use `PostMessage` to queue your own update. You can find the full code below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

const
  CM_CHANGEFORMAT = WM_USER + 101;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure ChangeFormatSettings(var Msg: TMessage); message CM_CHANGEFORMAT;
    procedure WinIniChange(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_WININICHANGE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyCurrencyString: string = '€';
  MyCurrencyFormat: byte = 3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ChangeFormatSettings(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  FormatSettings.CurrencyString := MyCurrencyString;
  FormatSettings.CurrencyFormat := MyCurrencyFormat;
end;

procedure TForm1.WinIniChange(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  {
    You will receive WM_WININICHANGE when you change regional settings.
    Just use PostMessage to update your own settings because your
    formatsettings will change after this message.
  }
  PostMessage(Self.Handle, CM_CHANGEFORMAT, 0, 0);
end;

end.
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

[`FormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatSettings) is a global variable. To have a specific interpretation of `CurrencyString`, use your own FormatSettings variable and the overloads that takes this variable during conversion.

See here for an example, [TFormatSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/TFormatSettings_(Delphi)).

To convert a currency to a string, utilizing your special FormatSetting variable and the overloaded [`CurrToStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.CurrToStr) function:

```
currStr := CurrToStr(Value,MyFormatSettings); // <-- Note the overload
```